# Java 7 parallel search for files recursively in a folder

Tags: parallel-processing, java-7, fork-join

I would like to use the Visitor API, in Java 7, to search for some files recursively in a folder. Since I will search big folders, with 100.000+ files, sparsed through folders, I would like to do this parallel.

But, I can't, for example, spawn a thread for each folder. May Fork Join may be an idea but , from what I've understood, FJ is usually used when you know the data, for example, you have a given array and you  want to process parts of 5 elements from it. So divide and conquer can be used very well in that case.

So can you please share your opinion of an idea that can allow me to search recursively for files fast ( must be parallel ) and also allow cancellation if the user desires so.

Thank you,
Ryu

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot use `Files.walkFileTree` for that (I assume that is what you mean when you say "the Visitor API, in Java 7"); you have to implement the directory traversal yourself to be able to parallelize it.

Fork/join does, actually, fit this problem very well. There is even a relevant example at [Fork and Join: Java Can Excel at Painless Parallel Programming Too!](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/articles/java/fork-join-422606.html). There is an example program in that article that "count[s] the occurrences of a word in a set of document" by traversing files in a directory, and all its subdirectories (recursively).

The author provides some seemingly positive speedup measurements in the discussion section, but you should consider what Dariusz said about the problem probably being IO bound rather than CPU bound (i.e., just throwing lots of thread at it will not result in any speedup after some, probably low, number of threads). It's surprising, at least to me at least, that the example program from the article was faster with 12 threads than 8 threads.

Cancellation, afaics, is an orthogonal issue to this, and can be implemented in some standard way (e.g., polling a `volatile` flag).

Answer (score 1):

I bet there will be no gain from parallel search on a single disk drive; the disk access/read time is significantly larger than any possible name comparisons you can make.

Did you actually write the code? Did you test it? Did you profile it? What have you deducted from profiling?

Remember that the first rule of optimization is: [**don't do it**](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Program_optimization#Quotes).

Comment: Hi Darius, exactly I was thinking of profiling, but the thing is I don't have any idea how to do it parallel in order to compare it with single threaded. But I was thinking that I have a CPU with 2 cores and hyper threading so theoretically, if I distribute 20.000 files/thread it should faster isn't it? I'll post when I get home some numbers for some files single threaded.

Comment: @aureliangtx you have to profile the single threaded version and check which task takes the most amount of time. You'll probably see that 90% of work time is the disk access function, and the remaining 10% is comparing names of files/folders. If you split that work into 2 cores you'd probably get around 4% (~1% for synchronization overhead) gain. You could go further and do the comparison while performing searches, but it's even more complicated. Then the gain would be 9-10%. Is it worth the work?